# Android 7.1.1 is reverting back to the Wi-Fi network with Internet, when we try to switch to a network without Internet in our App

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifimanager, android-7.1-nougat

We are manually switching WiFi on an Android device, from the currently selected network (with Internet) to a network that is provided by the Wireless Stick. This new network does not have Internet connectivity. These operations are performed using the WifiManager class, and networks are selected / deselected by adjusting their priority in the WifiConfiguration object for the desired AP. Other networks are given a lower priority. However, it appears that as of Android 7.1.1 this isn't enough and the network is reverting back to the one with Internet. Is there a different way such a network switch should be performed?